# How to get offset of <li> in nested <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the following HTML

```
<ul>
<li>List item one</li>
<li>List item two with subitems:
    <ul>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Final list item</li>
```

I am trying to find offset() of all 'li' including sub list 'li'. But it always returns same value for all 'li'

script

```
$('li').offset().left;
```

Is this correct? How to get the offset for all 'li' ?

Comment: $('li').each(function(){ $(this).offset.left; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop with `each` like

```
$('li').each(function(){
     alert($(this).offset().left);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `each()` to loop through all the `li` and get the corresponding `offset()`

```
 $('li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).offset().left); 
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Z4zUt/)